# Need help on Python

Tags: python, pangram

Q: A pangram is a sentence that contains all the letters of the English alphabet at least once, for example: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. Your task here is to write a function to check a sentence to see if it is a pangram or not.

What I have is:

```
def isPangram(s):
    alphabetList = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    alphabetCount = 0
    if len(s) < 26:
        return False
    else:
        s = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',s).lower()
                for i in range(len(alphabetList)):
            if alphabetList[i] in s:
                alphabetCount = alphabetCount + 1
        if alphabetCount == 26:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

However, when I try the example s=["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"], the result is False, which is wrong. It should be True b/c it has contained all 26 letters. Can anyone help me fix the code? Many thanks!!!

Comment: first thing i see - `len(s)`  could evaluate to `1` if s is a list. Just pass it the string instead

Comment: Note that `alphabetList` is predefined as `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're passing in a list of strings instead of a list. Simply pass in `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"` without the brackets and your code will work.

Your code is also unnecessarily complex (and mis-indented to boot):

```
if alphabetCount == 26:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

is way too complicated - `alphabetCount == 26` is already True or False! So you can simply write

```
return alphabetCount == 26
```

Additionally, you iterate over the input string with an index variable. This is completely unnecessary, just iterate over the input string, like this:

```
for c in alphabetList:
    if c in s:
        alphabetCount += + 1
```

On top - and that has caused the error now, since the code would have failed otherwise - the check for `len(s) < 26` is completely superfluous, just remove it.

The alphabet is also already built-in to Python, it's called [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase). So you don't need to write it yourself!

That being said, your algorithm is still really slow - you iterate over s 26 times! Why not simply write

```
import string
def isPangram(s):
    return set(s.lower()) >= set(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: Why are you using lambda to define a function just to assign it to a name? The whole and only point of lambda is that the function is anonymous and can be used in an expression; you're throwing away both benefits and getting all the disadvantages (e.g., the name in tracebacks will be `<lambda>` instead of `isPangram`). PEP 8 explains in more depth why you shouldn't do this.

Comment: But other than that, great explanation of what's wrong with the OP's code and all the ways it can be improved.

Comment: @abarnert You're right, lambda was only there for golfing purposes. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to reduce the letters in the sentence to a set, then verify that the set is the set of all letters.

```
def isPangram(s):
    alphabet = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    s = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', s)
    sentence = set(s.lower())
    return sentence == alphabet

assert isPangram("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
```

Comment: No need to use a regular expression here - just convert the string to lower case then do a set intersection and see if the string intersection with alphabet is equivalent to alphabet. `( set(s.lower()) & alphabet_set) == alphabet_set`

Comment: True; I was originally using the user's code as much as possible, and didn't remove that. Equivalently, you can check that `alphabet - sentence` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use sets:

```
def isPangram(s):
    alphabetset = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    set_string = set(s.lower())
    return set_string.issuperset(alphabetset)
```

Usage:

```
>>> isPangram('aabc')
False
>>> isPangram('aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
True
>>> isPangram('aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz J:L FSDJ f09823740235')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If s is array() s=["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"] you can only get a len()=1, then the if len(s) < 26: always return False

```
def isPangram(s):

    alphabetList = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    alphabetCount = 0
    if len(s) < 26:
        print "False 1"
    else:
        s = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',s).lower() 
        for i in range(len(alphabetList)):
            if alphabetList[i] in s:
                alphabetCount = alphabetCount + 1
        if alphabetCount == 26:
            print "True"
        else:
            print "False"
a=isPangram("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

Comment: What do you mean "If s is array()"? You're expecting it to be an `array.array('c')` or something? Even if it were, how would that be different from it being a list (as it appears to be) or anything else?

Comment: Always I asumme this "s" is array or you can try to compare with type (s)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove else statement after the line:

```
if alphabetCount == 26:
    return True
```

as it is putting the code into else condition for the i=0 itself because it is taking only one alphabet count.

```
import re
def isPangram(s):
    alphabetList = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    alphabetCount = 0
    if len(s) < 26:
        print('lenth is short')
        return False
    else:
        s = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',s).lower()
        print(s)
        for i in range(len(alphabetList)):
            if alphabetList[i] in s:
                print(alphabetList[i])
                print("The string is pangram2")
                alphabetCount = alphabetCount + 1
                print(alphabetCount)
                if alphabetCount >= 26:
                    print("The string is pangram")
                    return True
```

now the code is running properly